# font-style: italic vs oblique in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

What is the difference between these two:

```
font-style:italic
font-style:oblique
```

I tried using the [W3Schools editor](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-style) but was unable to tell the difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: Message from the future: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_type) has a very nice example showing the difference between [italic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Garamond_Roman_Italic.svg) and [oblique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oblique_type_example.svg).

Comment: Late follow-up question (or maybe this should go into UX?): What wolud be a real-world use case for specifically choosing the oblique variant? Isn't the italic variant "always" preferable?

Comment: @KlaymenDK: Admittedly, this is a narrow use case, but I can envision preferring an oblique font for legibility in certain small font sizes on pixelated outputs: Example: using a 6pt to 8pt font on a small form-factor screen; some italic forms have thinner strokes and more ornaments that may decrease legibility compared to a simple "slant".

Answer (score 312, accepted):

In the purest (type designer) sense, an oblique is a roman font that has been skewed a certain number of degrees (8-12 degrees, usually). An italic is created by the type designer with specific characters (notably lowercase a) drawn differently to create a more calligraphic, as well as slanted version.

Some type foundries have arbitrarily created obliques that aren't necessarily approved by the designers themselves... some fonts were meant not to be italicized or obliqued... but people did anyway. And as you may know, some operating systems will, upon clicking the 'italic' icon, skew the font and create an oblique on the fly. Not a pleasant sight.

It's best to specify an italic only when you're sure that font has been designed with one.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that almost no font families in the wild specify both Italic and Oblique faces, and most rendering engines will supply the other face if the specified face is unavailable for that font.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the functional differences, the mutual exclusivity, or semantic differences.

Comment: With Cyrillic fonts for example, the italic characters will often be very different, much more like the cursive form, the oblique form will just be oblique.

Comment: What is a rendering engine supposed to do if I say "italic" but there is only an "oblique" version of the font available? Or vice versa?

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination Your comment should've been the answer because it addresses the real technicality at place when it comes to CSS in particular. The "answer" chosen here is more on typography.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination, well, if Oblique is just skewing the normal font, then why should a font even bother to have a separate Oblique font face? From what I understand from the answers here, the application can just algorithmically skew a normal font to show an Oblique font, while true Italic font needs to be specifically designed for the hand-written-like styles.

Comment: @hellopeach Skewing the typeface algorithmically Might make the typeface look "bad" from the point of view of the font designer, even if the over all "slanted" look would be fine.  Having the separate face means the designer can correct any odd-looking artifacts that a totally algorithmic approach might cause.  One example of this is the font hints used in some of the more advanced typefaces.  Having a separate face allows a designer to put control points in places that give crisp lines with no skewing artifacts like uneven lines or aliasing jitter.

Answer (score 87):

Generally, an italic is a special version of the font, whereas an oblique version is just the regular version inclined a bit. So both are slanted and related to the regular font, but an italic will have special letterforms made especially for it.

Most fonts have either an italic or an oblique version; I've never seen one that has both. (If you have an italic version, why bother with an oblique version?)

Comment: Latin Modern is a well-known example of a font that has distinct oblique and italic styles. [In this tex.stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79086/105024), the styles are demonstrated.

Answer (score 28):

As with **italic** and **oblique**, the same difference is visible when comparing **italic** with **faux italic**.

You will see **faux-italics** wherever a **normal** font is skewed with `font-style: italic;` whereas a true italic font is designed to be slanted.

[image]

The bottom of the two ***ll***​s shows the difference clearly.

[**See Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SpaDzXmSb1oADxUfKVg1?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean oblique equals faux-italic?

Comment: Yes, if neither an oblique nor a italic font are available the results will appear the same (at least in chrome for this example) http://next.plnkr.co/edit/SpaDzXmSb1oADxUfKVg1?preview

Comment: could NOT have done this answer without a visual aid, thanks

Answer (score 24):

Oblique type (or slanted, sloped) is a form of type that slants slightly to the right, used in the same manner as italic type. Unlike italic type, however, it does not use different glyph shapes; it uses the same glyphs as roman type, except distorted.

**Futher Reading:**
[css font style oblique vs italic](https://www.zubair.info/blog/2010/11/05/css-font-style-oblique-vs-italic.html)

Answer (score 4):

According to [mozilla developer CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals) :

> italic: Sets the text to **use the italic version of the font if available**; if not available, it will simulate italics with oblique instead.
>
> oblique: Sets the text to use a simulated version of an italic font, created by slanting the normal version.

From here, we deduce that  **if an italic version of the font is not available**, both *italic* and *oblique* behave the same way. Since the W3Schools code snippet does not specify any particular `font-family`, I believe a default font is used; a default font which probably does not have an italic version.

**But how to make an italic version of the font available?**

This means that we have at least two versions of the same font, a "regular" one, and an italic  one. These can be specified in  the `<style>` section with the `@font-face` rule. Please read briefly : [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp), [tympanus.net](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/font-face/). As you can see, the font is loaded as a file, which can have the following extensions: `eot, otf, woff, truetype`.

So far, i found two ways of linking the font file

absolute URL of the font file: (code snippet from [tympanus.net](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/font-face/))

```
`@font-face {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), 
 url (http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

 @font-face {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 400;
 src: local('Open Sans Italic'), local('OpenSans-Italic'), 
 url 
 (http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/
 xjAJXh38I15wypJXxuGMBobN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff)
 format('woff');
 }`
```

Please notice that in both cases we have `font-family: 'Open Sans'`, which basically defines the same font; but in the first case we have `font-style: normal;`,  while in the second case we have `font-style: italic;`. Also note that the URLs point to different files.  **Now, going back to the w3schools code snippet, that's how the browser can distinguish between `font-style: normal` and `font-style: italic`**

using the relative path to the font file : (code snippet from [metaltoad.com](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles))

> Instead of defining separate font-family values for each font, You can use same font-family name for each font, and define the matching styles, like so:

```
`@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-I-webfont.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
}`
```

In this case, the `.eot` files must be stored in the same folder as the html page. Again, notice that the `font-family` is the same, the `font-style` is different, and also the urls are different: Ubuntu-**R**-webfont vs Ubuntu-**I**-webfont.

**Example of an italic version of the font:**

[ctan.org](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/anonymouspro/truetype/) :this is an example of how there are provided different files for different styles/weights of the same font. Neither bold or italic are computed on the spot, they are retrieved from their specific file.

Comment: my answer addresses the second part of the question: "... but was unable to tell the difference.    What am I missing?"