# How to do text formatting in php

Tags: php, css, echo, text-formatting

I want to do text formatting italic of my data which is echo from database. In my database, synonyms field their are more than one name and I retrieve all in one echo. For example Calappa nucifera (L.) Kuntze , Cocos indica Royle are store in my db. For this rezone i replace ',' with 'new line'and then echo. I want to show:

***Calappa nucifera* (L.) Kuntze**

***Cocos indica* Royle**

But my code shows:

**Calappa nucifera (L.) Kuntze**

**Cocos indica Royle**

My code is below:

```
echo '<div style = "margin-left: 150px;">'.str_replace(',','<br />',$row["synonyms"]).'</div>';
```

Comment: so, use `oblique` - Edit: or `italic`. You can pick whichever one you want, slightly different flavours to choose from. It's "CSS 101" stuff. You can read the differences here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680624/font-style-italic-vs-oblique-in-css

Comment: `style="font-style: italic;"` seems an obvious possibility

Comment: @RiggsFolly [*They have a choice.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054691/how-to-do-text-formatting-in-php#comment65458468_39054691)

Comment: why is there an mysql tag here? If it isn't relevant, it should be removed.

Comment: @Akib67 https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using inline style in your code you have bold only and not italic

then obtain the firts two word and in a proper span tag ad  font-style:italic;

```
$mySino = explode( ','),  $row["synonyms"]);

echo '<div style = "margin-left: 150px;">' ;
foreach ($mySino as $key => $myRow) {  

  $myValue= explode( ' ', $myRow,  3);

    echo  '<span style="font-style: italic;">' . 
           (isset($myValue[0]) ? $myValue[0] : '') .
       ' ' . (isset($myValue[1]) ? $myValue[1] : '' ) .
      '</span> ' .( isset($myValue[2]) ? $myValue[2] : '') . '<br />';
}

echo     '</div>'  ;
```

Comment: In my db a field is synonyms. Their are more than one name . For this reason i replace ',' in 'new line' and print this synonyms are new line . But i want to print first two word are italic and rest are normal . how i do this ?

Comment: Sorry :( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'style' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 26

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 26
3

Comment: @Akib67  .. i'm sorry  there are only until 2  ... answer updated .

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 26

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 27 
print 3

Comment: @Akib67  . have your some rows without  synonyms?  .. anyway i have update the answer

Comment: Yes . I have many rows. Sorry to say that , this is also error;(    Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 29

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 30
3

Comment: @Akib67  don't worry  .. i have update the asnwer .. hope this way manage the undefined  ..

Comment: Sorry :(                                                                                                 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php on line 29

Comment: I solve the lowercase problem but also showing error :(

Comment: @Akib67   .. i have update the answer  with a new explode syntax

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\tree1\details_page.php

Comment: It's done . but for first name , second name is normal text . Example:*Calappa nucifera* (L.) Kuntze, Cocos indica Royle. in my code i use string replase but this not done in this code ;(

Comment: Thanks. First full name are correct but for second and rest full name italic happened only first part. Example: *Bombax pentandrum* L.
*Ceiba* caribaea (DC.) A. Chev.
*Ceiba* casearia Medik. Eriodendron anfractuosum DC

Comment: @Akib67   .strange  .. could be that the words  ( alias the space between the word)  are not regular  respetc the row ?  .. or there is space after the comma  ..? thaht change the rules ?

Comment: eventually post  a full row  of sinonym for sample  not only a part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you asking about some sort BBCode handler,

```
<?php
function parse($value) {
    $findAndReplace = [
        '[br]' => '<br>',
        '[i]' => '<i>',
        '[/i]' => '</i>',
        '[b]' => '<strong>',
        '[/b]' => '</strong>'
    ];

    return str_replace(array_keys($findAndReplace), array_values($findAndReplace), $value);
}

$str = '[b][i]Calappa nucifera[/i] (L.) Kuntze[br][br][i]Cocos indica[/i] Royle[/b]';

echo parse($str);

?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Through I suggest using something like [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)

Comment: *Cocos indica* is supposed to be italicized. Not just "indica". Same for *Calappa nucifera*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for that, couldn't tell in the question, how's that?

Comment: In my db a field is synonyms. Their are more than one name . For this reason i replace ',' in 'new line' and print this synonyms are new line . But i want to print first two word are italic and rest are normal . how i do this ?

Comment: Good; yet it seems that the plot thickens ^ and I've asked the OP about that mysql tag; no response or code to support the question. Just a mere `$row["synonyms"]`.