# Mapping font-face to achieve the same font

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "EurekaSans";
    src: url("fonts/EurekaSans-Regular.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "EurekaSans";
    src: url("fonts/EurekaSans-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "EurekaSans";
    src: url("fonts/EurekaSans-RegularItalic.otf");
    font-style: italic, oblique;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "EurekaSans";
    src: url("fonts/EurekaSans-MediumItalic.otf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

Here I am trying to map the different fonts according to font-weight and font-style, however it does not do the job.. It only uses the italic version. Anyone spot the issue?

Comment: are you setting `font-family: 'EurekaSans';` on the elements you want to use this font?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680624/font-style-italic-vs-oblique-in-css

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I am setting it on body

Comment: You saved me of headache @A.Meshu